# Factory reset not working in Samsung Tab 2

Tags: factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

I want to factory reset my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2. I have tried to factory reset it through `Settings` and through hard reset but it again reboots with same account and applications. I have also tried to uninstall some applications but they reappear on reboot.

How can I factory reset my device?

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting through **Recovery mode**. if you have installed a custom recovery like philz or CWM try **wiping dalvik cache** and **user data** before Factory Reset.it will prepare a clean ROM for you to proceed.

hope it helps.